# Running janusGraph on windows

Tags: c#, windows, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying running JanusGraph on windows to local benchmarking and I have problems.
I'm running gremlin-server.bat and gremlin.bat but I don't have janusgraph.bat file in bin directory (only janusgraph.sh).
How can I do that? 
Thank You.

Comment: Googling "janusgraph.bat" led me here: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/950

Comment: @AKX I saw this, and still don't know. Can we use JanusGraph on windows? I think no, but maybe am not 100% right. What do You think? Have a nice day :)

Comment: In the end, it looks like the .sh script basically starts Gremlin, ElasticSearch and Cassandra. Start those manually?  https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/1a5a261a97dae68bda901b1b479bac70b55d17bf/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/static/bin/janusgraph.sh#L144-L185